# Maven Installation and Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

I have installed Apache Maven following these steps.

1. JDK and JAVA_HOME
   Make sure JDK is installed, and “JAVA_HOME” variable is added as Windows environment variable.
2. Download Apache Maven
   Visit Maven official website, download the Maven zip file, for example : apache-maven-3.2.2-bin.zip. Unzip it to the folder you want to install Maven.

Assume you unzip to this folder – C:\Program Files\Apache\maven

3. Add M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME
   Add both M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME variables in the Windows environment, and point it to your Maven folder.

M2_HOME or MAVEN_HOME
Maven document said add M2_HOME only, but some programs still reference Maven folder with MAVEN_HOME, so, it’s safer to add both.

4. Add To PATH
   Update PATH variable, append Maven bin folder – %M2_HOME%\bin, so that you can run the Maven’s command everywhere.
5. Verification
   Done, to verify it, run mvn –version in the command prompt.

   ```
   Apache Maven 3.3.1 (cab6659f9874fa96462afef40fcf6bc033d58c1c; 2015-03-14T01:40:2
   7+05:30)
   Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Maven
   Java version: 1.8.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
   Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre
   Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
   OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
   ```

But When I build a project in Eclipse LUNA, I get this error.

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\Sarnath K Jegadeesan\Documents\BroadLeafQuillingArtWorkspace\DemoSite\site\build.xml
start-db:
     [echo] Starting Data Base...
jetty-demo:
[artifact:mvn] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
[artifact:mvn] -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
[artifact:mvn] Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
```

I have all the environment variables properly set. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: It does say build successful, what is the problem here?

Comment: Did you reopen console after properties setting?

Comment: @Dragondraikk: See Last but 4th Line. -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set.

Comment: @AlexanderFedyukov Yes. But I still have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your Eclipse IDE edit Installed JREs and add following property in  Default VM arguments

> -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME

Window-> Preference -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Edit
[image]

Restart Eclipse and It will work fine :)

Comment: @Sarnath Jegadeesan , Update Maven and restart your System and try

Answer (score 0):

**First, you need to Locating the Environment Variables**

**1.** Open up the system properties **(WinKey + Pause)** and you should see the below screen.

[image]

**2.** From the system properties, tab select the **"Advanced"** link. This should take you to the below screen.

[image]

**3.** From the System Properties screen select the **"Advanced Tab"**. On this screen click the  **"Environment Variables"** button.

**4.** You should now be seeing something like the below screen.

[image]

**Now You Are Ready To Add Variables - Apache Maven**

In the **system variables** section click on the **"New"** button.

In here enter the variable name : **M2_HOME**

Enter the variable value as the location of the Apache Maven installed in the previous section. *(this is assuming you have already installed Maven into the desired folder if have not at this point do it now)*

For an example of my location below. (Please note the variable value will vary depending on your install location and version of Apache Maven installed)

[image]

Click ok to complete this action. Once completed you should see the **M2_HOME** variable in the list of system variables.

Next due to an idiosyncrasy within eclipse (only if you are using eclipse) you need to create another new variable called **M2** and point it at your newly created **M2_HOME** variable.

**Example below:**

[image]

Next, you need to add the newly created **M2_HOME** variable onto your path.

To do this locate the "Path" variable in the system variables list. Select it and click the edit button.

This should bring up the below option. *(For Maven   2.0.9 or newer versions, also be sure that the **M2_HOME** doesn't have a '\' as the last character.)*

Be sure to omit any quotation marks around the path even if it contains spaces.

[image]

Scroll to the end of the **"variable value"** and append on the following
**;%M2_HOME%\bin**

Click **"OK"** to confirm and leave the edit path screen.

Once complete click **"OK"** to confirm and leave the Environment variables screen.

Next, open a new command prompt **(Winkey + R then type cmd)** and run **mvn -version** to verify that it is correctly installed.

If it is you should see something similar to the below screenshot.

[image]

**Optional:** In the same dialog, add the **MAVEN_OPTS** environment variable in the user variables to specify JVM properties, e.g. the value **-Xms256m -Xmx512m**. This environment variable can be used to supply extra options to Maven.